# How to do a single build with GitLab for Vue application with multiple .env files

Tags: vue.js, webpack, gitlab, environment-variables, gitlab-ci

I have a simple .gitlab-ci.yml file that builds my Vue application. I build once and then deploy the `dist` folder to my various environments:

```
stages:
  - build
  - deploy_dev
  - deploy_stg
  - deploy_prd

build: 
  image: node:latest  # Pull Node image
  stage: build
  script: 
    - npm install -g @vue/cli@latest
    - npm install
    - npm run build
  artifacts:
    expire_in: 2 weeks
    paths:
      - dist/

deploy_to_dev:
  image: python:latest
  stage: deploy_dev
  dependencies:
    - build
  only:
    - master  # Only deply master branch automatically to Dev
  script:
    - export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=$DEV_AWS_ACCESS_ID
    - export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=$DEV_AWS_ACCESS_KEY
    - pip install awscli  # Install AWS CLI
    - aws s3 sync ./dist s3://$DEV_BUCKET
```

This all works great, however, I've now introduced some config and build my app differently per environment - for 3 environments I have 3 different build commands. Eg, I have an `.env.production` so for a production build my command becomes:

```
npm run build -- --mode production
```

Is there any way to get around having different builds for each environment but still using the .env files based on a GitLab variable?

Comment: Did you ever manage to work this out? I'm having the same issue but I can't work out how to build/deploy to different environments using Gitlab CI.

Answer (score 1):

You should split your build job to have one per environment and use the `environment` [concept](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/environments.html) to have something like that for `dev` and `production` envs :

```
.build_template: &build_template
image: node:latest  # Pull Node image
script: 
  - npm install -g @vue/cli@latest
  - npm install 
  - npm run build -- --mode $CI_ENVIRONMENT_NAME

build_dev:
  stage: build_dev
  <<: *build_template  
  environment:
    name: dev

build_prod:
  stage: build_prod
  <<: *build_template      
  environment:
    name: production
```

In this snippet, I used [anchors](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#anchors) to avoid duplicate lines.

Comment: OP has asked for single build